# If statement not working in cronjob

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, cron

bash cronjob continues to create a new process even though my `if` statement tells it not to run if the process or port already exists...

cat /etc/crontab

```
*/1 * * * * root /opt/script.sh
```

also tried:

```
* * * * * /opt/script.sh
```

the script opens a port so i tried checking port number using `lsof` to determine if the script was executed.

```
#!/bin/bash

port='1234'
if ! lsof -i | grep -o $port; then
    command ...
fi
```

but that didnt work, every 60 seconds another script.sh is executed and somehow there are multiple processes occupying port 1234. so i tried using `ps` instead of lsof.

```
#!/bin/bash

c=$(sudo ps aux | grep -o '[s]cript\.sh')
if [[ $c != 'script.sh' ]]; then
    command ...
fi
```

but that doesnt work either. whats going on here? maybe im misunderstanding how cronjobs work, because i cant figure out why the if statements arent working and preventing the command from executing again and again.

im using ubuntu 16.04, fully updated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion between different ways of adding `cron` jobs.

If you add a job with `crontab -e` there is no `user` column (the job is run as the current user), whereas entries in `/etc/crontab` must have the `user` column. Since your entries are in `/etc/crontab`, you need to use your first format (note that in the schedule time `*` and `*/1` are equivalent).

Provided that you are using the correct `crontab` entry, your script using `lsof` should work, although `grep -q` would stop unnecessary output. Note that `lsof` needs to be run as `root` in order to get a full list.

Your script using `ps` is more problematic:-

- The use of `sudo` is unnecessary if you are running as `root` and will fail otherwise, as it needs to prompt for the password; also, `ps` produces the same listing whether running as `root` or not.
- If there is more than one match in the `ps ... | grep ...`, then you need double quotes for correct syntax in setting `c`.
- If `c` is empty or there is more than one match, then `$c` in the test will need double quotes for correct syntax.
- If `c` contains more than one instance of `script.sh`, then the test will fail.

You could get round these problems by using the same technique as you used in the `lsof` script:-

```
if ! ps aux | grep -q '[s]cript\.sh'; then
    command ...
fi
```

By the way, I like the use of `[s]cript\.sh` to stop `grep` matching itself.